# Eclipse can't run java project with module warning

Tags: java, eclipse, module, swt

I'm running eclipse 4.16 with OpenJDK-14. I have a simple java project that has a lib folder with swt.jar in it. It was added to the modulepath in the project's Properties > Java build path > Libraries dialog. When I import and use an swt class in my class, I'm prompted to add an entry to my module-info file. It adds "swt" with a warning:

```
Name of automatic module 'swt' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name.
```

When I try to run the project as a java application I get this error in console and nothing runs:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module swt not found, required by ca.footeware.swt.converter
```

If I export the project as a runnable jar with dependencies enclosed, it works with a similar warning. The exported jar does run (but it's not a convenient development cycle :)

I read somewhere that for non-modular jars a MANIFEST.MF header, Automatic-Module-Name, can be used. I cracked open the swt.jar and added the header with value org.eclipse.swt, the root package of the jar. I removed the Requires swt; from my module-info.java and again was prompted to add an entry from my class with an swt import. This time though it entered Requires org.eclipse.swt; and no warning was produced. When I tried running the project however I got the same error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.eclipse.swt not found, required by ca.footeware.swt.converter
```

Comment: _"jar with dependencies enclosed"_ does not work using the modulepath since each module must be in a separate JAR (that's a limitation of Java, not of Eclipse). The unstable module name warning can be ignored (it's just a warning) but indicates that you use an outdated version of the SWT library (newer versions have `Automatic-Module-Name`). The simplest solution would be to delete your `module-info.java`. Otherwise, show the command line (in the run configuration there is a _Show Command Line_ button) and your `module-info.java`.

Comment: So no fat jars anymore? That sucks.

Comment: Fat JARs only when not using the modulepath (the different `module-info.class` files of the modules overwrite each other in the JAR since they are in the default package which means in the root folder inside the JAR).

Comment: Thanks @howlger. My command-line is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --module-path /home/craig/Downloads/swt.jar;/home/craig/workspace/ca.footeware.converter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p /home/craig/workspace/ca.footeware.converter/modules:/home/craig/Downloads/swt.jar --limit-modules java.desktop -m ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter.Converter and my module-info is module ca.footeware.converter {
 exports ca.footeware.converter.spi;
 requires swt;
}

Comment: That command line doesn't makes sense to me: both, `--module-path` and `-p`; ` --limit-modules java.desktop`. Please show your run configuration the tabs _Arguments_ and _Dependencies_ and the _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ the tabs _Libraries_ and _Module Dependencies_.

Comment: I posted to eclipse forums at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1831487/#msg_1831487 with screenshots of those.

Comment: So you specified `--module-path` in the run configuration in the _Arguments_ tab manually, right? But that would not have been necessary, because Eclipse already does that via `-p` (which is the shortcut for `--module-path`). So, does removing the `--module-path` argument also work?

Comment: Yes I specified --module-path and -m on the arguments tab of the run config. I emptied the Arguments tab and ran but got module swt not found. My run config's Dependencies tab lists:  swt.jar, ca.footeware.converter, and the JRE. My Command Line is  /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p /home/craig/Downloads/swt.jar:/home/craig/git/ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter/modules --limit-modules java.base -m ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter.Converter.

Comment: BTW @howlger, I really appreciate your help with this. If it helps, the project is on Github at https://github.com/CraigFoote/ca.footeware.converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! My Run Configuration's VM args is now:

```
--module-path ca.footeware.converter:ca.footeware.converter.temperature:/home/craig/Downloads/swt.jar -m ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter.Converter
```

I'm on linux and the --module-path separator should be :, not ;.

Note I've set the Run Configuration's Working Directory to ${workspace_loc} rather than the default ${workspace_loc:ca.footeware.converter} so that I could access both module projects by simple name rather than fully qualified name, e.g. /home/craig/workspace/ca.footeware.converter.temperature.

Comment: Still using VM args - not using the Run Config Dependencies tab.